# Why return a proxy class even for const member function for "copy on write"?

Tags: c++, string, proxy-classes

In More Effective C++, the following codes are given

```
const String::CharProxy String::operator[] (int index) const
{
    return CharProxy(const_cast<String&>(*this), index);
}
String::CharProxy::operator char() const
{
    return theString.value->data[charIndex];
}
```

Why don't we just return a char instead of using const_cast and casting CharProxy to char later?

Comment: I suppose the purpose of  doing this is to allow to take a pointer to the underlying character.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong in your case there is also the *non const* version to be able to both read/write the char and also as Real Fresh says to take a pointer/ref of the char.

Then it is natural to offer the same for the *const* version allowing to read the char (not write of course) and also take a pointer/ref (const) of the char.

You have that behavior with the *std::vector std::string* etc

Comment: So we will still get the updated char even when someone else modify the String. But actually copy of the String will happen when someone modifies it via non-const CharProxy. Maybe the point is the uniform interface for const and non-const operator [].

Answer (score 0):

You do this so that a `String::const_reference` (i.e. `const String::CharProxy`) bound to the return value of `[]` doesn't suddenly become dangling when *somewhere else* modifies that particular `String`.

You could define that mutations invalidated all references, but that would mean your `String` class would be unusable with a wide range of generic code, and is "Spooky action at a distance". E.g. you have code A first takes a mutable reference from the `String`, then code B takes a const reference, then A mutates through it's reference. Now code B's reference has become invalidated, and it can't have checked beforehand that this would occur.

Note that the proxy returns the `char` by *value*, so no references can escape.

Comment: This easier solution seems also OK and no dangling reference exists. ```char String::operator[] (int index) const
{
return value->data[index];
}```